# How to read Image file from within an Android application?

Tags: android, image

I'm new to Java & Android and need your help in resolving an issue. I am porting the code from Java to Android and need some pointers.

Below is my Java code and I am reading a image file from my desktop. I need to do something similar in Android.

### Java Code

```
BufferedImage img = null;
img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\john.jpg"));
```

Below is the Android code I have written. I have placed the image file in res/layout. I know i should not be placing the image file there.

### Android Code

```
Bitmap myimg = null;
String filename = "data/data/com.example.app/res/layout/john.jpg";
myimg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
```

Could you guys please let me know where to place the image file in my project and how to read the image file. Also, I'm using decodeFile in Android compared to read in Java. Which is better decodeFile or decodeStream? I don't want to place the image in assets folder. Please let me know the right approach, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you must put images in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`. These folder you will find in the `res` directory of your project.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResources(getResources, R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: Thank you Williams. The flow of my app is that, my MainActivity.java calls the main method of another class in a different file. The decoding code is written in that different file. I don't think getResources would work. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: In that case you can pass the `Activity` context then access like this in different file like `context.getResources`. This should work for which you are looking